# Movie set in or near China about a boy and his family's forced relocation

Tags: identify-this-movie

Which movie is this? (I've tried some internet searching without success)

- I saw it on video about 10 years ago, so 2005-ish
- It was about a boy and his family, who were forced to relocate from their farm to a city.
- There was a key scene involving the boy's horse.
- There was another scene where a person in the city kills himself/herself by jumping from building.
- I think it was set in China or a neighboring country.
- It was not a documentary.

Comment: Was it in English?

Comment: @Chanadler good question - I'm not 100% sure, but I believe it was non-English with English subtitles

Comment: Do you perhaps remember *when* they moved to the city? I mean, was it nearer the beginning or the end of the film?

Comment: I'm asking because there *is* a 2005 movie that fits the bill ([Season of the Horse](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499224/), about a family of Mongolian farmers forced to sell their horses and move into the city), but I can't even find clips and can only rely on what the interwebz are saying about it.

Comment: I think that is the one... Mongolian seems right, and the focus on selling-horses-to-move matches perfectly. (I think the move was at the beginning of the film, with lots of flashbacks to before the move - but I don't remember much.) Thanks much! Please put as answer, so I can accept!

Comment: @ShizZ. Sure, I'll put it up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This could be the 2005 film [Season of the Horse](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0499224/). The year and storyline seem to fit:

> Under the encouragement of the Chinese government, the traditional way of life of the nomads of the Mongolian plains change. Once a culture with a great emphasis on raising horses on the grassy plains, they are encouraged to move into the cities to work as industrial workers. However, one family tries to resist this change, trying to raise money to send their [boy] to school by selling yogurt. Unfortunately, this is hardly sufficient and they are forced to sell their beloved horses.

You can read more about it [here](http://www.smhric.org/news_86.htm) and in [this](http://variety.com/2005/film/reviews/season-of-the-horse-1200528094/) *Variety* review (I can't find any clips, unfortunately).

[image]

Comment: Congratulations, this is the winner of the [monthly answer challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1795/49).